# Need some help to choose beetween Allegro 5, SDL 1.2, SDL 1.3 or SFML

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sfml, allegro5

I won't start a debate about which library is better, it would be against the rule, but more ask a series of technical question. When i ask if there is special technique, just say the name of the technique, or a link.

Don't forget, im comparing also SDL 1.2 AND **SDL 1.3**, not just one of those

Which library have multiple window support?
I already know the answer for SDL: SDL 1.2, no, but 1.3 yes

Which of those library are multi-threading safe?

Most of the speed test were done when SDL and allegro were using software acceleration, but now that SDL 1.3, allegro 5, and sfml use hardware acceleration, in terms of speed, how do they compare?

Which of those library can detect more than one keyboard press at once? Is there any special technique to do so?

Is there a way to integrate the result in a GTK window? If yes, is there any special technique? (I remember last time i used SDL 1.2, i wasn't able to do this...)

Which library has support for 3d? (using openGL)

If i use X library with OpenGL for graphics, will there be limitation, or more/less features available? (I mean, is using opengl for graphics the same for all those libraries?)

Which of those libraries can I statically link to?

And finally, are some of those libraries more toward a particular game style? (Like X library is better used when making RPG, while Y library is more used while making strategy game, tile based game...)

Don't forget about **SDL 1.2 AND SDL 1.3**

**EDIT:**

I will try to share everything i found out, from my research, feel free to contribute to get more answer to my question.

Multiple window: SDL 1.3, SFML
No multiple window: SDL 1.2

Multi-threading safe: Allegro 5, [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/system-threads.php)

Not Multi-threading safe:

Speed: Unknown

More than one key-press support: SFML, Allegro 5

Comment: We generally answer one question, not lots. This is too much to ask at once.

Comment: Trying to circumvent not being a subjective question by asking many subquestions doesn't work. It's still a subjective ("which is better?") type question, and therefore doesn't belong here.